# API call successfully from external client but not from c#

Tags: c#, api, postman, rest-client, apiclient

I need to call client API-HTTPS (GET) with some specific headers

```
Accept:application/json,application/vnd.error+json
Date:2018-10-03T06:52:48Z
Authorization:<SECRETKEY>
```

In this scenario when I try to call it from client like **Postman** or **Advanced REST client**, API give proper result. But the same thing I tried with C# code which generates 401-Unauthorized errorcode.

For example If I'm using postman code for RestSharp (C#). It won't work from my code.
Postman screenshot:
[image: Postman screenshot]

Even I tried the same with **HttpWebRequest** and **HttpClient** too. But no luck.

Code which postman provided from **code section** is as below with some confidential information which I can't expose.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://**CLIENT_API_PATH**");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "ef8c2a79-a501-4cef-aa2e-bacdc9d3a922");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "**SECRET_KEY**");
request.AddHeader("Date", "2018-10-03T06:52:48Z");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json,application/vnd.error+json");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

In above code 3 parameters are compulsory and have to pass for successful call to API.

1. **Date** with the above mentioned format only.
2. **Accept** with above mentioned string only.
3. **Authorization** with specific authentication (custom by client).

As per suggested comment I also add fiddler data from the call.

1. Postman request fetch from fiddler
   [fiddler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwt5b.jpg)
2. C# api call code request from fiddler
   [fiddler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnZ0q.jpg)
3. C# code debug result
   [visual studio debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmfLM.png)

Comment: I didn't understand, does it work with the RestSharp code ? Where is your C# code?

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Code is in https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb59o.jpg. Some client specific detail which I can't expose.

Comment: i mean backend c# code.

Comment: No @sagi my client API does not calling from Restsharp code provided by postman.

Comment: We can not provide assistance for an issue of which you are not showing us the code used, you are instead giving us code which does work to tell us that it works? Is the RestSharp code above what's in your production application?

Comment: Can you check what request is being sent by your C# code by using a look like `Fiddler`? Probably you are not sending `Authorization` header or not in the format excepted by the API.

Comment: @ColinM : Yes above mentioned code is my production code using which I'm trying to call client API. This code is same from **code** section from postman by which API call was successful.

Comment: In that case, you need to provide the Authorization type. `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer **SECRET_KEY**");` This is what the answer below contains, but doesn't actually call out.

Comment: @ColinM : What suggested by '@muhammad-faisal' is by 'HttpWebRequest' but that doesn't work as I tried with 3 different libraries.

Comment: He suggests `HttpWebRequest`, and part of that code uses the correct format for Authorization tokens.

Comment: @ColinM: Yes you are right, but I trying to say that I tried with all that effort with different libraries and different way. But Now I only required which way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static string Get(Uri uri, string token)
{
    string responseString = string.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. Explain what your code does and why that would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Please confirm one thing. Which Authorization mode you are using while initiating request from Postman? Is it Bearer or something else?

Comment: @muhammad-faisal. I have to pass 2 more headers with **Authorozation**. Which are **Date** and **Accept**. But when I tried to put Date with above mentioned string it throws "Argument exception". Other alternative I already tried.